# MVC3 LINQ SubmitChanges Invalid

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, submitchanges, sql-update

In the method below db.SubmitChanges is shown as invalid/not recognized by intellisense.
This is my first attempt to update records in a database using LINQ and the method may contain other logic/syntactical errors that I havent yet uncovered as well.  What is causing the SubmitChanges to be incorrect?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq.Expressions; 

public void updateInfo(RefillViewModel _myRefillViewModel)     {                 
     try         {
         decimal patid = _myRefillViewModel.Patient.Patient_ID;
         decimal rxid = _myRefillViewModel.Rx.Rx_ID;

         CAHODEntities db = new CAHODEntities();

         List<Fill> FillList = db.Fills.Where(p => p.Rx.Rx_ID == rxid && p.Rx.Patient_ID == patid && p.Status == "UnFilled").ToList();

         foreach (var item in FillList)
         {
             if (FillList.Count() == 0)
             {
                 item.Status = "Requested";
             }
         }
         db.SubmitChanges();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using EF? Because in Entity Framework it's `SaveChanges()` not `SubmitChanges()`.